# Вводное слово после обращения. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация, вводные-слова

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли вторая запятая в предложении:
*"Алексей, может, тебе стоит еще подумать?"*
Интуитивно чувствую, что нет, но правила не нашел. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Спасибо всем а ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая после вводного слова **может** нужна. То, что вводное слово стоит после обращения, ничего не меняет.

**"Алексей, может, тебе стоит еще подумать?"**

[**МОЖЕТ, вводное слово**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_416&layout=item)

[**Знаки препинания при обращении**](http://lingvotech.com/znaki_prepinaniya_pri_obrashchenii)

Answer (score 0):

Алексей, **может**, тебе стоит еще подумать?

Вводное слово **обособляется** (другой грамматической роли у этого слова здесь нет), но **интонационно оно не выделяется** (при такой структуре предложения это трудно сделать), поэтому принцип постановки запятой чисто грамматический.

Именно поэтому **кажется, что запятая не нужна**.

Answer (score 0):

Обращение тут ни при чем. А "может" в роли вводного обычно обособляется по общему правилу.

Так что **запятая нужна.**

++++++++

Я вот подумала. Единственным мотивом для отсутствия запятой тут может служить понимание слова "может" как частицы. Но тут как-то совершенно такого не получается. Да, список частиц не исчерпыващий, встречается случаи, когда в роли частицы выступает неожиданное слово. Да, в чем-то это "может" сходно с "узаконенными" частицами (типа "правда", "пусть"). Но при этом "может" имеет личную форму глагола (не повелительного наклонения, что важно) и является стяжением "может быть". 
Не проходит такая идея. 
А других значимых мотивов что-то и не просматривается.